# Bernoulli's beam equation approximative solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve a problem of approximate solution of a Bernoulli's beam equation by numerical integration in Python for which I already posted a question in the stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017578/python-solving-bernoullis-beam-equation-with-scipy).
I however suspect that I have a problem in the mathematical understanding of the problem. Runge-Kutta's method of numerical integration only accepts the first order differential equation, so I have to use a new variable to transform the original equation.

Bernoulli's beam equation for a cantilever beam with a point load P at the free end:
$$
E*I*y''−M(x)=0
$$
$$
y'' = -(P/(E*I))*x
$$
Boundary conditions are
$$
y(x=L) = 0
$$
$$
y'(x=L) = 0
$$
$$y'''(x=0) = F
$$
If I understand this correctly, this is a linear, second order, non-homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients, which has a neutral form of;
$$
y'' + a1(x)*y' + a2(x)*y = f(x) 
$$
and the coefficients a1 and a2 are equal to zero.

Then I need to implement a new variable h to reduce the order:
$$
y' = h
$$
$$
dh/dt = x
$$
Does this means that I'm implementing a function h and a variable t. I just can't wrap my head around this. Does this perhaps mean that instead of second order differential equation, I'm getting a set of 2 first order differential equation?
Also, when I define the y' as h, this means that I have to integrate y'' to define h? When I do this using non-definitive integrals, I get an unknown constant C. How do I implement this numerically?

I searched for explanations of this, but I only found them for order reduction of ordinary diff equations of second order, while the beam equation above is not ordinary?

Comment: How do you get to your second order equation from the 4th order beam equation in the linked article, $(EIy'')''=q$? You can decompose this as second order system $M=EIy''$, $M''=q$, but the second equation does not appear in your formulas.

Comment: I did not start with the 4th order as this was the procedure we used in school. You take the 2nd order equation, define the moment equation and continue from there with the exact solution. Now I want to have a method for the approximate solution because I want to plot the deflection of the beam when I is not constant, I = f(x)

Comment: So you are in the case of a cantilever beam with end load at $x=0$, $M''(x)=P\delta(x)$, so that $M(x)=Px$ for $x>0$. It would be helpful if you could also formulate the boundary conditions in more detail, that is, the conditions at the ends of the beam (and where they are)?

Comment: I added the boundary conditions in the OP.

Comment: The third order condition adds a slight complication as you get $I(0)y'''(0)+I'(0)y''(0)=-\frac{P}{E}$, so that $I(0)F=-\frac{P}{E}$, so $P$ is determined by the other constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have
$$y''=f(x)$$
Integrate
$$y'=\int f(x)\,dx+ c_1=F(x)+c_1$$ Integrate again
$$y=\int F(x)\,dx+ c_1x+c_2$$

Comment: That with the combination of boundary conditions would be the exact solution of this equation. In the case in the OP, the geometry of the beam is simple and I = constant. I want to have a quick solution when the I = f(x).

Comment: @user2882635 : The same applies, only that you have to employ a numerical quadrature method. In general, quadrature is more simple than ODE integration.

Comment: I tried that and had a discussion about it in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986667/python-integrating-a-function-and-plotting-results 
Sadly the results were not satisfactory. I tried the way of ODE integration because of the suggestion of user gboffi, that the quadrature method of integrating in a loop is "Sub-optimal in the sense of the ratio accuracy over computational effort."